# How we can recover MySQL database (Innodb,myisam)

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.5, recovery

I have found some recovery tool [innodb-recovery](https://innodb-tools.googlecode.com/files/innodb-recovery-0.3.tar.gz) but it works only on linux machine, I would like to know how to recover innodb tables on windows.

- Transaction ID based recovery
- Cancel based, Change based recovery
- Point in time based recovery

Let me know if any of the blogs are available for this, and looking for good information.

Comment: Did You already have a problem, or look for recommendations - how best organise recovery strategies? h-m-m question - too old, just was showing in active questions :-)

Answer (score 2):

First of all don't use this version. The recovery toolkit migrated to LaunchPad and since then version 0.4 and 0.5 were released. But even 0.5 is outdated because I never had a chance to release a lot of useful features and bugfixes which are still in the trunk. The current home of Percona Data recovery toolkit is https://launchpad.net/percona-data-recovery-tool-for-innodb

After I quit Percona I forked the data recovery toolkit and made undrop-for-innodb ( https://github.com/twindb/undrop-for-innodb ) which includes Percona's features + performance optimizations and even more bugfixes.

But it still works on Linux only.

To use it on Windows there are two options:

1. Create a virtual machine and run it on Linux. InnoDB files format is same on Linux and Windows (and any other OS InnoDB supports) so the tool will perfectly work with InnoDB files from Windows environment.
2. Use online service https://recovery.twindb.com/ . It's a frontend to the toolkit and of course you can use it on Windows. However not all possible scenarios are implemented so depending on your case you may be left with option #1 only.